# How can I check for null using few ifs while running UBL XML Reading

Tags: java, xml, nullpointerexception, ubl

As you can see an example in the code below, I need to use a lot of if. Otherwise it throws null pointer exception.

```java
if (despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact() != null) {
                                    if (despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact()
                                            .getTelephone() != null) {
                                        tfdesp000_arch.setDcpPartyContactTelephone(despt.getDespatchSupplierParty()
                                                .getParty().getContact().getTelephone().getValue());
                                    }

                                    if (despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact().getTelefax() != null) {
                                        tfdesp000_arch.setDcpPartyContactTelefax(despt.getDespatchSupplierParty()
                                                .getParty().getContact().getTelefax().getValue());
                                    }

                                    if (despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact()
                                            .getElectronicMail() != null) {
                                        tfdesp000_arch.setDspPartyContactElectronicMail(despt.getDespatchSupplierParty()
                                                .getParty().getContact().getElectronicMail().getValue());
                                    }

                                    if (despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact().getName() != null) {
                                        tfdesp000_arch.setDspContactName(despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty()
                                                .getContact().getName().getValue());
                                    }
                                }
```

How do I avoid this null pointer exception using few ifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a single function which performs the null checks and reuse it:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

interface Despatch {

    SupplierParty getDespatchSupplierParty();
}
interface SupplierParty {

    Party getParty();
}
interface Party {
    Contact getContact();
}
interface Contact {
    Telephone getTelephone();

    Telefax getTelefax();

    EMail getElectronicMail();

    Name getName();
}
interface Telephone {
    String getValue();
}
interface Telefax {

    String getValue();
}
interface EMail {
    String getValue();
}
interface Name {
    String getValue();

}
interface TFDESP000_ARCH {

    void setDcpPartyContactTelephone(String value);

    void setDcpPartyContactTelefax(String value);

    void setDspPartyContactElectronicMail(String value);

    void setDspContactName(String value);
}
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Despatch despt = ...;
        TFDESP000_ARCH tfdesp000_arch = ...;

        // shorter version
        Contact contact = despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact();
        setContactField(contact, Contact::getTelephone, Telephone::getValue, tfdesp000_arch::setDcpPartyContactTelephone);
        setContactField(contact, Contact::getTelefax, Telefax::getValue, tfdesp000_arch::setDcpPartyContactTelefax);
        setContactField(contact, Contact::getElectronicMail, EMail::getValue, tfdesp000_arch::setDspPartyContactElectronicMail);
        setContactField(contact, Contact::getName, Name::getValue, tfdesp000_arch::setDspContactName);
    }
    
    private static <T> void setContactField(Contact contact, Function<Contact, T> getField, Function<T,String> getValue, Consumer<String> setter) {
        if (contact != null) {
            T field = getField.apply(contact);
            if (field != null) {
                setter.accept(getValue.apply(field));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the types may be wrong here, as you haven't given the signatures of your methods. For instance, if `getValue` doesn't always return `String`, you can add another type parameter to the `setContactField` method:

```
private static <T,U> void setContactField(Contact contact, Function<Contact, T> getField, Function<T,U> getValue, Consumer<U> setter)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the logic of the set methods, add the null checks there.

- setDcpPartyContactTelephone(...)
- setDcpPartyContactTelefax(...)
- setDspPartyContactElectronicMail(...)
- setDspContactName(..)

Example Code:

```
public void setDcpPartyContactTelephone(Telephone telephone) {
    if(telephone != null) {
        String value = telephone.getValue();
        //Continue normal operations
    }
}
```

Declare the contact as a variable:

```
Contact contact = despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact();
```

Your full code would look like:

```
Contact contact = despt.getDespatchSupplierParty().getParty().getContact();
if(contact != null) {
    tfdesp000_arch.setDcpPartyContactTelephone(contact.getTelephone());
    tfdesp000_arch.setDcpPartyContactTelefax(contact.getTelefax());
    tfdesp000_arch.setDspPartyContactElectronicMail(contact.getElectronicMail());
    tfdesp000_arch.setDspContactName(contact.getName());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that e.g. `getTelephone()` may return `null`.

Comment: Ah I see, then perhaps you can modify the setDcpPartyContactTelephone(...) method to take the Telephone as a parameter instead. I updated my answer with the example.